# DBeaver See transactions called from Node.js

Tags: postgresql, dbeaver

I am trying to debug an app of what transactions is run in the db.

When I open Query Manager I can see transactions run from within DBeaver, but I would like to log all the transactions called by the app to the db. Similar to what you found in Server status in pgAdmin3 before. Is that possible? 
I have a sneaky feeling that the SQL that Node is printing to my console is actually not the same as the one being committed.

Thanks

Comment: In Postgresql you would turn on logging in postgresql.conf, log_min_duration_statement = 0 # -1 is disabled, 0 logs all statements

Comment: Had to do a few other changes but this work